# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are getting this error

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in AuthenticationsController#create
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: token
```

Prior to this, we had tokens expiring that prevented posting on our web app, so in order to fix this we are trying to update the token and secret attributes each time users authenticate using a provider.

Here's the code:

```
class AuthenticationsController < InheritedResources::Base
def create
  omniauth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
  if authentication
     user = User.find(authentication.user_id)
     user.update_attributes(:token => omniauth["credentials"]["token"])
     user.update_attributes(:secret => omniauth["credentials"]["secret"])
     flash[:success] = "Signed in successfully"
     sign_in_and_redirect user
  elsif current_user
      #rest of the code here#
```

Here's the schema

```
 create_table "authentications", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "secret"
    t.string   "token"
  end

     create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string    "name"
    t.string    "email"
    t.timestamp "created_at",                         :null => false
    t.timestamp "updated_at",                         :null => false
    t.string    "password_digest"
    t.string    "remember_token"
  end
```

Here's the authentication model

```
class Authentication < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :provider, :uid, :token, :secret
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to assign token and secret to User model vs doing it for Authentication model.

```
 authentication.update_attributes(:token => omniauth["credentials"]["token"], :secret => omniauth["credentials"]["secret"] )
```

should work.

Comment: thanks for the response. any ideas why the attributes are not getting updated though?

Comment: You were trying to update the columns(token and secret) which doesn't exist in users table.

Comment: I meant, any idea why the token and secret columns still do not update after changing the code to `authentication.update_attributes`?